Discord Bot Command not showing as command
I'm trying to make a bot that shows a command such as "/help" but the /help isn't working at all, and not showing.
I've tried giving the bot different permissions and re-inviting the bot many times. I changed around some stuff but idk what the issue could be.
I'm not sure what to do as nothing works, i don't know if it's my bot or not. My node verison is correct
// Import required modules
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, EmbedBuilder, PermissionsBitField, Permissions } = require('discord.js');
const { ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, ComponentType, ActionRowBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require('discord.js');

// Create a new Discord client
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, // Enable intents for guilds
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, // Enable intents for guild messages
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, // Enable intents for message content
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions, // Enable intents for guild message reactions
  ],
});

// Set the bot token
const token = "Bot Token"

// When the client is ready, log the bot's username to the console
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});


// Define the help command
const helpCommand = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('help')
    .setDescription('Get help with various issues.');

// Handle interactionCreate event
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand() || interaction.commandName !== 'help') return;

    // Check if the command was used in a guild channel
    if (interaction.channel) {
        // Check if the command was used in the expected channel
        if (interaction.channelId !== 'Channel ID') {
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'This command is not available in this channel.', ephemeral: true });
            return;
        }
    }

    // Create the buttons as raw JSON components
    const buttonsRow1 = [
        {
            type: 2, // Button type
            style: 3, // Button style (SUCCESS)
            label: 'Ban Info',
            custom_id: 'ban-button'
        },
        {
            type: 2,
            style: 3, // Button style (SUCCESS)
            label: 'Tools Status',
            custom_id: 'first-button'
        },
        {
            type: 2,
            style: 1, // Button style (PRIMARY)
            label: 'Program Not Running',
            custom_id: 'second-button'
        },
        {
            type: 2,
            style: 1, // Button style (PRIMARY)
            label: 'Failed Error',
            custom_id: 'third-button'
        }
    ];

    const buttonsRow2 = [
        {
            type: 2,
            style: 1, // Button style (PRIMARY)
            label: 'Cracked',
            custom_id: 'fourth-button'
        },
        {
            type: 2,
            style: 1, // Button style (PRIMARY)
            label: 'DLC Cars',
            custom_id: 'fifth-button'
        },
        {
            type: 2,
            style: 1, // Button style (PRIMARY)
            label: 'Credits',
            custom_id: 'sixth-button'
        },
        {
            type: 2,
            style: 1, // Button style (PRIMARY)
            label: 'Add XP',
            custom_id: 'seventh-button'
        }
    ];

    const buttonsRow3 = [
        {
            type: 2,
            style: 1, // Button style (PRIMARY)
            label: 'Add Wheel-spins',
            custom_id: 'eighth-button'
        },
        {
            type: 2,
            style: 1, // Button style (PRIMARY)
            label: 'Disable AC Error',
            custom_id: 'ninth-button'
        },
        {
            type: 2,
            style: 1, // Button style (PRIMARY)
            label: 'AIO V2 Virus?',
            custom_id: 'tenth-button'
        },
        {
            type: 2,
            style: 2, // Button style (SECONDARY)
            label: 'Exit',
            custom_id: 'exit-button'
        }
    ];

    // Send a reply with buttons
    await interaction.reply({
        content: 'Help Command Recognized\nIf you\'re having an issue or want a solution, click on one of the buttons to get an answer for your question.',
        components: [
            {
                type: 1, // Action row type
                components: buttonsRow1
            },
            {
                type: 1,
                components: buttonsRow2
            },
            {
                type: 1,
                components: buttonsRow3
            }
        ],
        ephemeral: true
    });

    // Handle button clicks
    const collector = interaction.channel?.createMessageComponentCollector({ time: 60000 });

    collector?.on('collect', async (buttonInteraction) => {
        if (buttonInteraction.customId === 'ban-button') {
            await buttonInteraction.update({ content: 'Ban Info button clicked', ephemeral: true });
        } else if (buttonInteraction.customId === 'first-button') {
            await buttonInteraction.update({ content: 'Tools Status button clicked', ephemeral: true });
        } else if (buttonInteraction.customId === 'second-button') {
            await buttonInteraction.update({ content: 'Program Not Running button clicked', ephemeral: true });
        } else if (buttonInteraction.customId === 'third-button') {
            await buttonInteraction.update({ content: 'Failed Error button clicked', ephemeral: true });
        } else if (buttonInteraction.customId === 'fourth-button') {
            await buttonInteraction.update({ content: 'Cracked button clicked', ephemeral: true });
        } else if (buttonInteraction.customId === 'fifth-button') {
            await buttonInteraction.update({ content: 'DLC Cars button clicked', ephemeral: true });
        } else if (buttonInteraction.customId === 'sixth-button') {
            await buttonInteraction.update({ content: 'Credits button clicked', ephemeral: true });
        } else if (buttonInteraction.customId === 'seventh-button') {
            await buttonInteraction.update({ content: 'Add XP button clicked', ephemeral: true });
        } else if (buttonInteraction.customId === 'eighth-button') {
            await buttonInteraction.update({ content: 'Add Wheel-spins button clicked', ephemeral: true });
        } else if (buttonInteraction.customId === 'ninth-button') {
            await buttonInteraction.update({ content: 'Disable AC Error button clicked', ephemeral: true });
        } else if (buttonInteraction.customId === 'tenth-button') {
            await buttonInteraction.update({ content: 'AIO V2 Virus? button clicked', ephemeral: true });
        } else if (buttonInteraction.customId === 'exit-button') {
            await buttonInteraction.update({ content: 'Exiting...', ephemeral: true });
            collector.stop(); // Stop the collector
            client.application.commands.create(helpCommand);
        }
    });

    // Handle the end of the collector
    collector?.on('end', () => {
        interaction.editReply({ content: 'You ran out of time, try again.', components: [] })
            .then(() => {
                interaction.deleteReply();
            })
            .catch(console.error);
    });
});

client.login(token)


You must register your slash commands to use them.
The DiscordJS guide has a great resource on how to do this. It's a little too involved for a full answer here.

I will try this thank you very much, I'll be back if everything goes well thank you very much/

Glad I could help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If I was able to answer your question, please make sure to mark it as accepted so others can find it.
